# Changing the value of Timeout depending on the array value

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I want to print alphabet from array every 0,5 second and everytime its a vowel every 2 seconds.

I managed to write a code printing array elements every 0,5 second

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
var i = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(alphabet[i]);
            i++;
        }, 500*i)
}
```

How do I implement the rest

```
if (alphabet[i] == 'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u'){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(alphabet[i]);
        i++;
    }, 2000*i)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Side note: The `i++;` you have inside the `setTimeout` callback doesn't do anything useful, it increments a variable that will never be used by any other code. (Every loop iteration gets its **own** `i` variable when you use `let` in the `for` declaration like that -- which you want above, that part is correct, just remove the unnecessary `i++;`.)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Promise()`, you can use the `Promise.all ()` command, where `Promise.all()` waits for all Promises in the array to be processed.

```js
function setIntervalForItem(input = [], vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"], defaultInterval = [500, 2000])
{
  const [interval, _interval] = defaultInterval;
  var resultPromiseArray = new Array();

  for (const char of input) {
    const delay = vowels.indexOf(char) === -1 ? interval : _interval;
    resultPromiseArray.push(new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({value: char, time: delay});
      }, delay);
    }));
  }
  return Promise.all(resultPromiseArray);
}

var alphabet = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
  'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
];

// Then just call:
setIntervalForItem(alphabet)
  .then(result => {
    for (const object of Object.entries(result)) {
      const {value, time} = object[1];
      console.log(`The delay for character [ ${value} ] was ${time} ms`);
    }
  });
```